# Can I change the brightness on a secondary display?

Tags: display

I have a MBP with a secondary display. Is is possible to have the brightness keys (F1 & F2) change both the main display (laptop screen) and the secondary display (a VGA external monitor connected via a Thunderbolt port with an adapter)? If not, is it possible to change the brightness on the secondary display?

Comment: What is the brand and model of the external display, and what is the means of connection? (VGA, Thunderbolt, DVI, Mini DisplayPort). It is always helpful to give full specifications when you ask a question.

Comment: I'm looking to solve the same problem but with a Mini DisplayPort monitor. For more on this topic check out: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/61045/does-apple-support-ddc-ci-for-3rd-party-displays-via-apples-thunderbolt-to-dvi

Not surprised that Apple doesn't give a damn about standards.

Comment: Please change the correct answer to the one with the most upvotes so that people are sure to see it. Thanks!

Comment: Use my own fork of **Brightness Menulet**, it supports auto adjustment based on the `ambient light sensor` https://github.com/MuhammadHewedy/BrightnessMenulet

Answer (score 67, accepted):

One of my favorite tools for doing this is [Shades](http://www.charcoaldesign.co.uk/shades) which is "donationware."

You can adjust each monitor separately, and set keyboard shortcuts for them as well.

If you want a command line solution, I found [brightness.c](http://dev.sabi.net/trac/dev/browser/trunk/LocationDo/) which compiled cleanly using:

```
gcc -std=c99 -o brightness brightness.c -framework IOKit -framework ApplicationServices
```

It will let you set the brightness for either monitor.

Another tool available at: [Command-line display brightness control for macOS](http://github.com/nriley/brightness)  or just `brew install screenbrightness`.

Comment: Fixed (again). Sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the fixed link.  It only works for my laptop display on my setup under 10.8, though. When I try to set the external it says "failed to set brightness of display 0x4246511 (error -536870201)"

Comment: Dead link to your precompiled version.

Comment: https://github.com/superduper/BrightnessMenulet Very good (and tested on `Dell S2340L`) for non-apple monitors but AFAIK works only for main display (where the menu bar appears)

Comment: I was able to compile brightness.c just fine, and it works on the built in monitor.  Like @JoshuaGoldberg, it errs out when the external display is connected.

Comment: Note that this answer is 4 years old. There is a newer tool available at https://github.com/nriley/brightness or `brew install screenbrightness`

Comment: I tried all of the above (brighness.c, brew install brightness), as I prefer command line based approaches, and the only one that worked with my external displays was "Shades", which doesnt support command line, but works ;-)

Comment: Shades was the one for me! I have a unique situation where I connect my macbook to an old imac for which I do not have a keyboard. The imac stays locked, but it automatically switches displays. Unfortunately it blocks volume/brightness controls. Shades fixed brightness controls for me!

Comment: Shades doesn't work with Catalina anymore.

Comment: This answer is from 2011. I'm guessing Shades was 32-bit.

Comment: The formula name is even shorter now: `$ brew install brightness`.

Answer (score 157):

**On Apple displays**, if you press <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd> or <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd> the brightness on a secondary display will adjust. I have tested this on my MacBook Air 2011 13" and 27" Thunderbolt Display.

**Important note:** You have to plug in the USB cable from the Display to the Macbook Pro in order that the keyboard shortcuts work.

If you're using a MacBook with Touch Bar, this works for the "brighter"/"less bright" Touch Bar *buttons* but **NOT** for the Touch Bar brightness *slider*.

Comment: I don't have a Thunderbolt Display. I have a standard VGA monitor, but I will try it.

Comment: On my Mac Pro (with two DVI displays), 10.7.4, this does not work.

Comment: This works for my MacBook Pro with dual Thunderbolt displays.

Comment: This doesn't work with displays other than Apple's I think.

Comment: Worked perfectly with my studio display and imac setup.  Thanks!

Comment: This is BRILLIANT! Works very well with dual thunderbolt display setup with MacBook in clamshell mode. Wish I can award 100 points for this! The only thing missing how is how to sync the brightness on the displays, but this is already a huge step forward.

Comment: @abbyhairboat Thinking about buying another display, what happens if two thunderbolt displays are attached? Does this change the brightness on both at the same time?  What if you want a different brightness on one vs the other?

Comment: @y3sh Not sure as I only have two displays atm. I know that adding "shift" switches the brightness control from one monitor to the other; maybe that'll be the secret with 2 thunderbolt + 1 built-in. I can't imagine any key combo would change brightness on more than one display at a time.

Comment: All this did for me was select the apple icon in the top left of the monitor.

Comment: I agree with user1380540. The shortcut wasn't working to adjust the brightness. But, when I connected the USB cable of the thunderbolt display, and opened my system preferences --> Display, it gave me the option to adjust the brightness. I am on MBP Retina Mid 2014, Mac OS Sierra 10.12.5 with 24-inch LED Cinema Display.

Comment: The touchbar slider shows two separate sliders in target display mode as well.

Comment: This used to work brilliantly, but after the last Mac OS X 10.15.7 update, stopped working!

Comment: This does not work for a MacAir M1 (2020) running Monterey 12.0.1 connected to an Apple LED Cinema Display (MB382LL/A - A1267) via USB C hubs

Comment: It worked per perfectly with LG UltraFine 24MD4KL. I was not able to find `Control` + `F1` option nowhere in official documentation.

Answer (score 115):

[Lunar](https://lunar.fyi/) is an app which allows you to automatically sync the system display brightness with the brightness of an external monitor.

With Lunar, **you can use the standard display controls (and keyboard keys!)** to adjust the brightness simultaneously on the main and external display, which is exactly what I wanted. It also supports tweaking of brightness and contrast ranges/offsets to get exactly the desired levels.

Lunar is not restricted to any specific display type or connection method, so it should work with most displays connected over USB-C, Thunberbolt, etc.

Comment: can't believe no one upvoted this answer lol the only answer worked for me. thank you thank you thank you!

Comment: Of all the solutions here, this seems to be the only option that supports adjusting the brightness of the built-in MacBook display and an external non-Apple monitor *simultaneously*.

Comment: Lunar is now found at:  https://lunar.fyi/

Comment: Perfect solution as it can also sync with the brightness level of your Mac and is easy to use and open source.

Comment: Great, but need to pass Security Policy restrictions :)

Comment: And the best part is that it changes the native brightness of the monitor settings. The monitor settings also show the change of brightness as reported by Lunar.

Comment: Lunar works with both: brightness and contrast setting, and allows to configure coefficient curve, how external monitor bright/contrast corresponds to internal auto-brightness enabled monitor. Worked perfectly on my external Lenovo L220x connected via two adapters USB-C->HDMI + HDMI->DVI. Works on MacOS 10.15 Catalina

Comment: Great solution!

Comment: The configuration options on this are so good, and it works so well.  Thanks for recommending it.

Comment: This worked for controlling brightness of an Apple LED Cinema Display (MB382LL/A - A1267) connected via USB C hubs to a MacAir M1 (2020) running Monterey 12.0.1

Comment: Doesn't work well for me. There's a problem with syncing the monitor to the display. Adjusting brightness of the monitor where the cursor is also didn't work. MBP 2015, ASUS PA278QV

Answer (score 59):

Knowing that this question is rather old I want to make you aware of https://github.com/the0neyouseek/MonitorControl which is open source, well maintained and quite handy.

[image]
[image]
[image]

You can control brightness, contrast or volume directly from a menulet or with keyboard native keys. Keyboard keys even display the native osd.

Comment: If you have two external monitors they can't be independently setup

Comment: This is the only answer that worked for my LG Ultrafine monitor. Thanks!

Comment: Clean and simple! Love it!

Comment: This is the only answer that worked for my Acer CB282K - can finally turn its brightness down to match MBP. Needs to use display controls to turn dark boost to zero to improve contrast.

Comment: This is the real answer everyone!!!!!!

Comment: The newest version (v4.1 at this time of writing) even uses the system standard controls (e.g. TouchBar in my case) and synchronises brightness with the native display as Lunar is reported to do!

Answer (score 22):

Another option is [Brightness Slider](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/brightness-slider/id456624497?mt=12), free in App store.

Comment: seems to set the same brightness to all screens

Comment: Wow, it works like a charm even for the macos with damaged discrete gfx card, when you can not change the brightness with the standard keys,

Comment: As of today it only controls the brightness of the main monitor.  I think Ina's issue was reported as a bug and maybe they "fixed" it.  To me, setting all the screens to the same brightness is the correct behavior.

Comment: Beautiful little app — does exactly what I need it to. Done.

Comment: Like ina said, Brightness Slider only dims the main display. There's an app called Quickshade that dims all displays like Brightness Slider, just better IMO

Comment: ina said the opposite @travisjayday but to me it also looks like Brightness Slider only dims the main display and Quickshade does both. Dead simple. Just the right tool for ppl who, like me, don't understand how lunar works anymore

Comment: It does not really manage the monitor brightness, but it does the job if you configure the monitor brightness to 100 and then manage the software brightness with this tool

Answer (score 14):

Unfortunately, Macs don't have access to an external display's brightness settings. On most displays, that is only controllable using the physical buttons/menus on the display itself.

I agree that this would be a great feature to see, but it isn't really possible now to control brightness over the video cable.

Note that I can't speak for Apple's Cinema Display and Thunderbolt; I haven't tried that and it may be different.

Comment: Yeah, I'm talking about a standard VGA monitor. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

If you're using an Apple Cinema Display it is possible to control brightness as long as you connect the display's USB cable to your Mac. The causes a "Brightness" slider to appear on the screen's control panel in "Displays" System Preferences. Unfortunately the F1 and F2 don't change the brightness settings on the external screen.

Comment: Macbook Pro ( 2015 ) with external 24" Cinema display only uses control F1 / F2 if the USB is connected.  Just having the thunderbolt connection is not enough to get the F1/F2 to work.

Answer (score 5):

If you have an Apple Cinema display and are adjusting brightness via the "displays" preference pane, note that the preference pane will show up both on your main display (the cinema display) and on the MBP. It allows you to set the brightness separately.

Answer (score 5):

A dead-simple program called [Brightness Control](http://www.splasm.com/brightnesscontrol/index.html) has been dimming multiple external monitors for me since 2006. Still working fine on OS X 10.11 in 2016.

[image: Brightness Control.app]

Only drawback is that you cannot simultaneously run [f.lux](https://justgetflux.com). If you only have one external monitor, you can use [Shady](http://instinctivecode.com/shady/) to dim that without quitting f.lux.

Comment: Shady seems to only dim one display on OS X 10.11 (if you connect your monitor after Shady is already running, it will dim your main display which doesn't solve the problem). Restarting Shady after connecting an external monitor seems to force it to change the brightness on the secondary display.

Comment: My habits have changed some. I now dim my built-in display with the keyboard controls (I’ve come to prefer turning down the backlight vs. a semi-transparent overlay), and for my external displays I use a different ancient program called [ScreenShade](http://screenshade.en.softonic.com/mac/download). Fair warning, the original host site has been taken over by malware people so don’t let it open their tutorial on the web. I like ScreenShade for monitor selection flexibility and the keyboard shortcuts (option-plus and option-minus).

Comment: There seems to be a problem with CTRL+<left/right arrow> to switch between Spaces on the main display while using ScreenShade.

Comment: @victor Hmm, bizarre. I haven’t had that problem. I’d say double check your keyboard shortcuts in OS X Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Mission Control. Otherwise, no idea... the app is from 2008 so no surprise it’s a little janky.

Comment: Toggled the "Move left a space" hotkey and restarted ScreenShade, works fine now.

Answer (score 5):

You can use https://github.com/kfix/ddcctl - works for my Dell P2715Q
And even better there is https://github.com/czarny/Brisync which even syncs brightness with your internal display

Comment: Brisync is perfect for situations where your screen is close to a window or when the difference between sunny or overcast weather can really affect readability. Thanks! 

Answer (score 4):

[Screen Dimmer](http://screendimmer.atlaswegman.com/) isn't free ($2), but is the only tool I could find that handles multiple monitors (up to 3).

Seems nice and elegant the short time I've used it. Sits in menubar, and has a simple slider and monitor selector, as well as keybindings for brightness increase/decrease.

My 3 external displays are non-apple (1 Dell with displayport, 1 samsung with displayport->dvi, and 1 old acer 19" with hdmi->dvi) on a MacBook Pro Retina 15" with 10.8.2.

edit: For the OP's question this shouldn't matter, but fyi for 3 monitors - it seems to only allow one combination of monitors for dimming (i.e. can't dim completely separately -- this works for me as I use it to dim the 2 side monitors so they don't distract from the main middle monitor)

edit2: The website appears to be down so here is the [App Store link](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/screendimmer/id562058942?mt=12). Also of note it allows for dimming up to 3 monitors but remember your MacBook does count as 1 if it's open. If you have 3 externals this means you can't dim the far right one. But, you can just close your MacBook and then you can dim all 3 externals.

Answer (score 3):

I have two screens connected to my Mac Pro. (This also works for MacBook Pro.) I have the USB on the first screen connected to the Mac. The second screen has its USB connected into the back of the first screen (the 2nd screen display adapter uses an extender to get to the Mac - you could likewise use a USB extender to get to the back of the Mac).

With both screens communicating to the Mac via screen as well as USB, <kbd>F1</kbd> and <kbd>F2</kbd> as brightness control the dimming of the first display, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> control the second screen. No need to disconnect at all.

Answer (score 3):

I tried most of the other suggested solutions. On the latest High Sierra with a non-Apple external display over usb-C these suggestions didn't work. I did stumble upon an app called EasyOnTheEyes that actually does the trick. https://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/easyontheeyes/id799584781?mt=12 . It hasn't been updated in a while, but still seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

I have 2 thunderbolt displays connected to my MBP. I had to connect only one display at a time in order to adjust the brightness. Then I reconnected them both and all was well. Too bad the control panel doesn't show the brightness slider on both displays but this is a simple solution.

Answer (score 2):

There are many answers here, but one wasn't mentioned (though it only has limited applicability---you need to have a second keyboard handy.)  When I have a second display hooked up to my MBP, *and* a second keyboard plugged in, then the built-in laptop keyboard's function keys control the built-in (main) laptop LCD and the external keyboard's function keys work for the secondary.

In case it's changed, this is on 10.6.8.

Comment: This has worked for me for the last couple OSX versions (Mavericks, Yosemite).

Answer (score 2):

I have MBP early 2011 connected to LED display and Thunderbolt display and I use the thunderbolt display as extended desktop.

This is how you can adjust the brightness on second display.

1. Press <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>. This will mirror the displays.
2. Press <kbd>F1</kbd> or <kbd>F2</kbd> and both screens will increase or decrease in brightness.
3. When you are done, press <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and your screens will revert back to extended desktop mode.

Ok, its a pain if you are like me and have items configured on both screens but I found using "shades" the second monitor was always looking dimmer and not the same brightness as the primary screen.

Answer (score 1):

After experimenting with lots of hot keys I found a solution.
I am using a dual screen setup with 27 inch iMac which is connected to a 27 inch Thunderbolt screen.

Using <kbd>cmd</kbd>+ <kbd>F1</kbd> (mirror displays) will also duplicate the screen brightness of screen 1 to screen 2.

Now you can dim the 2nd screen with <kbd>F1</kbd>

Repeat the <kbd>cmd</kbd>+ <kbd>F1</kbd> and the 2nd screen will revert to last brightness.
Now you can dim the iMac screen with the brightness keys.

Comment: Didn't work for me...

Comment: Cmd+F1 mirrors the whole display, not just the brightness.

Comment: Yeah, it does mirror whole display, but this fixes some weird bug, when you're gaming in a fullscreen mode, sometimes your 2nd screen would have very low brightness, this trick fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

Open System Preferences;
Click Displays;
In the lower left hand menu, click the Show displays in menu bar;
Once your menu bar has the little icon of your monitor, click it and select 
Open Display Preferences;

All monitors will have a Preferences menu linked to that specific object.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a 24" thunderbolt display which has a USB cable in addition to the thunderbolt cable,
**you have to have both plugged in**.
Then Ctrl + F1 and Ctrl + F2 should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [MonitorControl Lite](https://github.com/MonitorControl/MonitorControl/releases) to install a widget that lets you do this.[image: MonitorControl Lite controlling 2 of my monitors]

Answer (score -2):

If you run Windows Vista, Windows 7, or Windows 8, you can adjust brightness easily with [Mac Brightness Control](http://www.macbrightness.com/product.html) utility.

Comment: Yes, but does it allow you to change the *secondary display's* brightness?