# Does Apple support DDC/CI for  3rd party displays via Apple's Thunderbolt to DVI adapter

Tags: display, thunderbolt

I had a Dell 21.5" monitor, which was previously connected to a Windows PC via its DVI port, which has no problem with DDC/CI which allowed me to control brightness and Contrast of the attached display via Windows.

My question is: through Apple's adapter, can I control a non-Apple display within System Preferences?

Comment: For me, a similar setup does not enables me to control the brightness.

Comment: @MaxRied wow, that's encouraging LOL

Comment: Is DDC/CI listed as a feature on your Dell Display?

Comment: @MrDaniel Yes, it is listed as a feature.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I wish it were possible too, but the short answer is no, you can't use System Preferences to control the brightness of an external display via DDC/CI.

It might be feasible to write a program that can adjust the brightness of your external display, but it's by no means a sure thing. Read on if you want the gory details…

---

After doing a fair bit of research, I'm pretty sure that Apple doesn't use DDC/CI to control the brightness of displays, either internal or external.

1. The brightness of Apple Cinema Displays [can only be adjusted when the USB interface is plugged in](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/20307/33154). With DDC/CI this would not be necessary.
2. Apple provides (though apparently does not document) an interface to display brightness through their IOKit library, specifically in [ioGraphicsLib](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/IOKit/Reference/IOGraphicsLib_header_reference/Reference/reference.html):

   - http://mattdanger.net/2008/12/adjust-mac-os-x-display-brightness-from-the-terminal/

   …but this interface does not seem to work reliably for external displays:

   - http://njr.sabi.net/2006/06/20/setting-display-brightness-updated-tool/

   ( I read up on this a few years ago and while I can't now find a supporting link, I seem to recall that display brightness (at least for internal displays) may be delegated to Apple's [System Management Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Management_Controller) (SMC), which has responsibility for all power-related functions: fan speed, monitoring battery level, etc. I wouldn't be surprised if Apple had implemented their own I²C control interface between the SMC and the internal display - but this is pure speculation on my part. )
3. It is possible to communicate with/control external displays using DDC/CI and custom software, but support for this has been [broken more than once](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1835384) in the OS X era. DDC/CI support is also dependent on the [graphics chipset and drivers used](https://forum.luminous-landscape.com/index.php?topic=70796).

   From http://update.necdisplay.com/spectraview/readmemac_v1_1_12_1.html:

   > As of Mac OS 10.8.0, support for monitor connunications[sic] via
   >   DDC/CI is not functioning on some Macs, including systems with DVI
   >   video outputs, and when using a miniDisplayPort to DVI cable or
   >   adapter. NEC is working with Apple to fix this issue in a future Mac
   >   OS update.
4. DDC/CI works over [I²C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%C2%B2C). Apple's IOKit library includes an [I²C interface](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/IOKit/Reference/IOI2CInterface_iokit_header_reference/Reference/reference.html) which should make it possible to write a display control program, but there are a few reports that this does not work reliably (specifically, values can be written to the monitor but not read, so you can't tell what the current brightness is):

   - http://lists.apple.com/archives/colorsync-users/2011/Feb/msg00026.html
   - http://lists.apple.com/archives/darwin-dev/2012/Jul/msg00019.html
   - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11561623/i2c-communication-in-iokit-on-mac-os-x

So that's about the size of it, as far as I can tell.

If you are (or you know) an Objective-C developer, I did find a [project on GitHub](https://github.com/jontaylor/DDC-CI-Tools-for-OS-X) that you could have a look at tinkering with – however as mentioned above, even assuming the code is OK, it might not work for your combination of monitor, Mac and display drivers.

Comment: I appreciate the gory details. Thanks for doing so much organizing and link curation on this.

Comment: Thank you so much for the github project who worked amazingly well! I’ve looked this for years!
I’ve got a Dell u2311h on a 2011 MacBook Pro with OS X 10.8.4.

Comment: @user53454 -- How did you get it to work?

Comment: Note for display link users, the execution of the app will freeze the displays and you'll have to forze reboot :(

Comment: It's not about Apple. There are a lot of 3rd party apps that can control brightness via DDC/CI (even for macOS). The only issue that if use connectors to connect monitor that it's not going to work. E.g. it works ok if I plug VGA cable directly to D-Sub port of motherboard. If I plug it via connector (DVI-VGA) to DVI-D port of motherboard then it doesn't work https://items.s2.citilink.ru/1062424_v01_b.jpg

Answer (score 12):

Disclaimer: I compiled this app myself(although I'm not the author). **It may freeze your machine.**

You can also try this app: https://github.com/superduper/BrightnessMenulet, though it allows to adjust brightness only on main display(one where menu bar appears).

I've tested it on my MacBook Pro + Dell U2412M, worked fine.

Comment: Looks promising, but for the record nothing happens when I launch it on OSX 10.7.5 on MBP '12 with a HP ZR2440w over Mini Displayport.

Comment: Doesn't do anything for me either. Doesn't even appear in menubar. 10.7.4. @Victor -- what OS are you running?

Comment: Unfortunately this froze up my machine (mini, 10.8.current, dell 24" monitor via displayport).

Comment: This froze my Mac. No offense, but I suggest any future reader take extreme caution when trying this out. It's not malicious of course, but save your work before opening this.

Comment: Any news on this?

Comment: My hackintosh is running on Intel HD 4000 and a Dell 24 monitor (DVI) and a Phillips 24-inch monitor (HDMI). On Windows I know an application that can change the brightness of both of the two monitors, so it must be possible to do so. I tried this app, but the problem is, it only controlled the Dell monitor. Probably not designed in the multi-monitor in mind.

Answer (score 10):

Apple *software* doesn't support any means to control PC monitors beyond sleeping them.

The hardware adapters will pass DDC commands through if you can send them by other means.

I use many DisplayPort/Thunderbolt to DVI adapters as well as USB-to-VGA with my [ddcctl](https://github.com/kfix/ddcctl) program.

Try running `ddcctl -d 1 -b ?` to test whether your 1st monitor's brightness can be polled.

Then to increase the 1st monitor's brightness by 5 "ticks" (the scale varies from monitor mfg/model):

```
$ ddcctl -d 1 -b ? -b 5+
2015-06-19 11:46:14.081 ddcctl[39871:4302046] I: found 2 displays
2015-06-19 11:46:14.081 ddcctl[39871:4302046] I: polling display 1's EDID
2015-06-19 11:46:14.102 ddcctl[39871:4302046] I: got edid.name: LG ULTRAWIDE
2015-06-19 11:46:14.103 ddcctl[39871:4302046] D: command arg-pair: d: 1
2015-06-19 11:46:14.103 ddcctl[39871:4302046] D: command arg-pair: b: 5+
2015-06-19 11:46:15.108 ddcctl[39871:4302046] D: querying VCP control: #16 =?
2015-06-19 11:46:15.212 ddcctl[39871:4302046] I: VCP control #16 = current: 42, max: 100
2015-06-19 11:46:15.213 ddcctl[39871:4302046] D: relative setting: 42 + 5 = 47
2015-06-19 11:46:15.213 ddcctl[39871:4302046] D: setting VCP control #16 => 47
```

Comment: Thanks! I do need to reiterate the warnings though, ddcctl (and other ddc apps) can crash OSX, don't use it with unsaved work.

Comment: I like to keep my monitor at 0 brightness (super dim), but when people come and look at my screen they get annoyed by this, so now I have a way to easily bump to maximum for them. I used automator to make a `MaximumBrightness.app` (and a minimum one, too).

Comment: Sorry, how do I install this? I downloaded zip from github, unzipped, and did a `make install` from within that folder, but it throws up a bunch of errors: http://pastebin.com/aLpjLhdH

Comment: UPDATE: it does work despite the warnings.

Comment: what about "DVI-D VGA" converter? https://items.s2.citilink.ru/1062424_v01_b.jpg

Comment: no, it's not working when using such connector, it's bad that macOS stopped supporting VGA, so on my hackintosh I have to use this connector `D: NSScreen #1127274006 (1920x1080 0°) 102.00 DPI
I: found 1 external display
I: polling display 1's EDID
I: got edid.serial: DL11042508502
I: got edid.name: Philips 222E
D: action: b: ?
D: querying VCP control: #16 =?
E: No data after 10 tries! 
E: DDC send command failed!
E: VCP control #16 (0x10) = current: 0, max: 0`

Comment: @user25 I got nearly identical output from my Phillips 58PUS6809/12 TV. Seems like it cannot accept DDC commands at all?

Answer (score 7):

It's an old topic, but I'll still post it here, just in case.

I'm not sure about specific details of TB-to-DVI adapter, but in general you CAN control quite a lot of monitors. There's a great little free program called [MonitorControl](https://github.com/the0neyouseek/MonitorControl) by [the0neyouseek](https://github.com/the0neyouseek/), it gives you option to control brightness, contrast, and even volume on external monitors.

I personally tested it with Samsung P2450, AOC G2460F, Dell S2240M, and even old 4:3 Samsung 710n VGA via adapter, and it worked without problems at all.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The program works perfectly fine on Mojave even with multiple external displays, native brightness hud and really old Dell displays!

Comment: +1 for this being the accepted answer. Works perfectly with 2021 M1 MacBook Pro

Comment: +1 for this being the accepted answer. Works perfectly with 2021 M1 MacBook Pro

Answer (score -1):

I have a Thunderbolt monitor and Macbook Air. By using CTRL-F1 and CTRL-F2 the monitor's brightness can be adjusted.